# Issue with Managed Metadata as a Search Refiner in SharePoint 2013 Server Standard [VIDEO]

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, search-results, managed-metadata, managed-property

I am quite experienced with SharePoint in general, but not much specific to Search. I am having some challenges setting up a search page and wondered if you could help?

**ENVIRONMENT**: SharePoint 2013 Server Standard, with Publishing Infrastructure turned on (was activated just recently, not on site collection creation).

**GOAL**: configure a page that uses search to display all content in the site collection that is tagged with the Managed Metadata tags Document Type(Policy, Procedure, or Guideline). Allow user to filter (refine) search by Document Type and Originating Business Area to quickly find the content they need.

**WHAT I HAVE DONE**:

1. Created Managed Metadata, Site columns, and Content types to support the fields to be searched.

   2. Created document libraries and lists that use the content types that contain the site columns mentioned above. (Note the Document Type allows "select multiple" in most instances),
   3. Used Search Results at Site Collection level to define a search result limited to Policy Procedure Guideline.
   4. Added Crawled Property ows_taxId_Document_x0020_Type to Managed Property RefinableString00
   5. Added Crawled Property ows_Business_x0020_Area to Managed Property RefinableString01
   6. Created a Wiki page and added Search Results web part. Configured to use the above results source.
   7. Added Refiner web part to that Wiki Page and configured to use RefinableString00 and RefinableString01

**ISSUES**:

1. Refiners show a mess of Metadata Tag IDs rather than the actual tag values
2. I want to simplify the Display Template to Show single lines with File Name, Title, Business Area (etc.), similar to a basic Document library display, but (preferable) with hover panel to preview. Any suggested template to start with, or article to read?

**HERE'S A VIDEO OF WHAT I'VE DONE AND WHAT I AM SEEING: https://youtu.be/oPV8mmx54b4**

Thanks for your help!

Gerry

Answer (score 1):

thanks for looking, it turns out I was typing the refiner to ows_taxid_fieldname rather than ows_fieldname.  I had fixed this, but needed to wait for a full crawl before I saw that it was, in fact fixed.